# Problem sending Emails using android phone

Tags: email

I am new to this forum. I have come to this forum through google search and find interesting which leads me to signing up to this forum.

My boss is facing problem sending messages using business-email-account[image] from their android phone. It's a very rare case where the client successfully received mails but most of times when my boss check "Sent Mail" after sending mail it shows nothing. when he send mail, in Outbox it shows "Failed". Please see below screenshot, where my boss is trying to send mail to me.

*** Actual SCENARIO:

When my boss send mails at home using their jio sim (mobile data), mails are not send but when he send mails using the office wifi mails are send everytime (No chance of message failed). However, mails are received successfully regardless of using any kind of network connection.

So please any help me out of this strange problem. Please ask for more info if required...

Comment: What email app is that? What kind of email server are you using? Could it just be that the SMTP server is not accessible from outside the office network? Please [edit] your question to add all the required details.

Comment: @Ems ask your boss to try to use a different mailing app, and not the one that is supplied with the phone. Let us know if he faces the same problem in the other app also.